# unbinding hover() - not the normal case

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, unbind

I have a jQuery that, whenever the document is ready, binds a hover event with a handler to an element with the `class="widget-box"`. The issue is that once the document is ready, the hover event handler gets binded, but when the user clicks a button on the page, ajax is used so that part of the page is reloaded and then document ready causes the hover event to be binded again to the same element. I don't want this behavior to occur and only want the hover event to be binded once. I've tried to unbind hover() whenever document ready gets called again with unbind('mouseenter') and unbind('mouseleave') but somehow, that doesn't work to remove the hover that is already binded. Does anyone have any ideas as to how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: any chance you could post your code?

Comment: can you post the js and html snippets in question... its not 100% clear where the issue is. I understand from your description whats happening but i dont know enough to say what the solution is exactly.

Comment: well I can show the js but I'm actually integrating my code with someone else's and the told me that they use ajax to reload the page but never showed me where in the code it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have done something wrong. Do it this way:

```
$(".widget-box").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave').bind('hover', ...);
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score -1):

try using the .live() method:)

to qualify:

why are you loading the same javascript twice? if you only load it once, and use .live rather than .hover you can still attach your events to pertinent elements without having to run the js again.

EDIT:

have you considered just wrapping your code in something like:

```
if(document.myScriptIsLoaded!=true){
    document.myScriptIsLoaded=true;
    //put your document ready here
}
```

Comment: well what happens right now is that my javascript is loaded by someone else's code that is called by ajax requests and I can't control how many times a user presses a button and causes the ajax to load the page. But your live() idea might work; let me try it